# I have n(large) number of small sized txt files in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have n(large) number of small sized txt files which i want to merge into k(small) number of files

Answer (score 0):

if you have `hive table` on top of these `txt files` then use

```
insert overwrite <db>.<existing_table> select * from <db>.<existing_table> order by <col_name>;
```

Hive supports **select and overwriting same** table, order by clause will **`force to run 1 reducer`** which results only 1 file to be created in the directory.

However if you are having large data then `order by` clause will not perform well,  then use [`sort by (or) clustered by`](https://www.guru99.com/hive-queries-implementation.html#3) clause to initiate more than 1 reducer.

```
insert overwrite <db>.<existing_table> select * from <db>.<existing_table> sort by <col_name>;
```